# Python Dataframe column operation using lambda function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am solving below problem -
Given the dataframe df, define a function called multi that takes two arguments x and y that returns x multiplied by y. Use a lambda function inside the df.apply function to multiply the columns num_legs and num_specimen utilizing the multi function you defined, and then store the final result in a new column called result in the same datagram. Must use df.apply

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'],
                   'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen': [10, 2, 1, 8]})
df["result"] = df[["num_legs","num_specimen"]].apply(lambda row : row["num_legs"] * row["num_specimen"], axis=1)
df
```

I want to assign lambda function to variable multi and call that variable to create df["result"]

Comment: my question is to solve this in particular fashion where I want to use lambda function assigned to a variable(multi). I want to call multi inside df.apply and pass the values to it which is not answered

Comment: Finally able to solve this, it can work like -
multi = lambda frame : frame[0] * frame[1]
df["result"] = df.iloc[:,[1,3]].apply(multi,axis=1)